# Why my terminal does not see the running android emulator?

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

I'm trying to run our react native app in Android emulator, after `yarn android` the Emulator starts but the app doesn't and after a few seconds I get the following error:

```
yarn run v1.22.10
$ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1755 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: Could not start emulator within 30 seconds..
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: spawn ./gradlew EACCES
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

The project runs perfectly in XCode (ios), also in my colleague's laptop (with Windows).

I'm using a Macbook Air m1, macOS 11.3.1, SDK Platform: Android S, Android Studio 4.2.2, yarn version v1.22.10, node v15.12.0,

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure you have your **Android Environment** setup correctly.

To verify run

1. `echo $ANDROID_HOME`
2. `echo $PATH`

and make sure both have the correct path to your Android SDK.

If it's not correct, you have to set up your **Android Environment**

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Reference [react-native-official-setup-guide](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

Other than that, the major issue which I see is related to **Macbook Air M1**, I just face a similar issue, **M1** doesn't support **VT-X**.

To make sure that, your **Macbook Air M1** supports **VT-X** open `Android Studio` and then `AVD Manager`.

Example (My Macbook) (Marked in PURPLE Box, VT-X is not supported)
[image: VT-X not supported]

**Solution to this:**
Download new emulator from [android-emulator-apple-silicon-preview](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/12/android-emulator-apple-silicon-preview.html)

> This should enable developers to test/run ARM64 apps via ARM64 hardware virtualization.

Answer (score 0):

Here might be a react-native configuration issue with the current development environment on your system.

Please have a close look at the official docs to set up the environment.

[React native Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

Answer (score 0):

For the "Error: spawn ./gradlew EACCES at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)".

Please try to input:

```
chmod 755 android/gradlew
```

in the root directory of the project. Then:

```
npx react-native run-android
```